# Which means $E = E ''$ when $E$ is a reflexive space?

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

We know that canonical immersion $J_E: E \rightarrow E'' $ is an immersion of a normed vector space $E$ in its bidual. In case the space $ E $ is reflective, this gives an isometric isomorphism. But does that really mean that $ E = E ''$? For example, in an exercise, knowing that $E$ is reflective, I proved that $ M = (M^{\perp})^ {\perp} $ for all closed subspace $M$ of $E$, where $M^{\perp} = \{\phi \in E'\ ,: \phi (x) = 0 \,\, \forall x \in M \} $, but for that I actually proved that $ J_{E}(M) = (M^{\perp})^ {\perp}$. How should I argue to conclude from this that $ M = (M^{\perp})^ {\perp} $?

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to tell us what $E$ is.  For example, you mention "closed subspace" in there.

Comment: $E$ is a normed vector space and $M$ is a closed subspace of $E$.

Comment: That should be added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't conclude that $M = (M^\perp)^\perp$ in the sense of equality as sets since elements of the right hand side are functions on $E'$ and not elements of $E$. In this setting, that equality is always to be interpreted as equality up to the canonical identification of $E$ as a subset of $E''$ given by $J_E$. That is, the goal is to prove that $J_E(M) =(M^\perp)^\perp$.

Comment: I managed to prove that $J_E(M) =(M^\perp)^\perp$. Then so even though the exercise says explicitly that $M =(M^{\perp})^{\perp}$, I must interpret that equality is in the sense of canonical immersion, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help